# What is the connection between these LibGDX concepts?

Tags: java, libgdx

In LibGDX, what is the connection between these concepts: stage, camera, viewport, batch (spritebatch), projection matrix, tiledmap?

Currently my game has

**3 stages:**

- UI stage
- entity stage
- tiledmap stage

**2 cameras:**

- hud camera (for UI)
- map camera (for map)

**2 batches:**

- spritebatch for rendering particles
- batch from the tiled map renderer (used in map and entity stage)

**3 viewports:**

- for entity stage
- for UI stage
- for tiled map stage

I am very confused at this point at how all these components connect. My whole game works, except when I resize my main menu screen, the particles in my next screen get drawn in the wrong position. Meaning that the resize information does not reach the particle drawer.

I feel like the reason I am having a lot of trouble debugging it, is because I don't understand well enough how they relate to each other.

Can anyone help me clarifying this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain this based on my own experience so this might be not correct. For more trusted information check this out in case you didn't know: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

**Stage**

Imagine the stage as the container holding all your elements that need to be rendered/updated.

**Camera**

Determines what parts of the stage are visible (based on the viewport)

**Batches**

Are responsible for rendering everything (doing all the needed open gl stuff)

**Viewport**

Manages the camera and controls how the stage is displayed on the screen (aspect ratio etc)

To help you with your problem some screenshots / code pieces would be useful but sounds like after resizing the new viewport dimensions are not send to the batch rendering the particles

I hope this helped a bit but again for better information take a look in the wiki.

Blakk